# Android - buttons go off the edge of the screen, but text view fits in the screen

Tags: java, android, button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6iQF.jpg)

I firstly added the button, and try to add new text view, but when I infer constraints, the button goes off the screen. I tried to change the margin_Top, end, right, bottom, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button a `width` and `height` but not zero.